# Increasing the number of iterations with multisvm

Tags: matlab, svm

I'm attempting to use the multisvm function in matlab. On a small data set, everything works great. Increase the size where I need it, and I get the following error:

> Error using seqminopt>seqminoptImpl (line 198) No convergence achieved
>   within maximum number of iterations.
>
> Error in seqminopt (line 81) [alphas offset] = seqminoptImpl(data,
>   targetLabels, ...
>
> Error in svmtrain (line 499)
>       [alpha, bias] = seqminopt(training, groupIndex, ...
>
> Error in multisvm (line 20)
>       models(k) = svmtrain(TrainingSet,G1vAll);

I've been trying to look for a solution online and found this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/66183,

where the advice is "so increase the maximum number of iterations". The problem is, this doesn't seem to be easy to do. I am somewhat of a novice, but am trying to figure this out on my own by looking through all these files, without success. Does anyone know how I can increase the number of iterations and solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Svmtrain is trying to find a correct line between e.g. two groups. If it doesn't find correct line, it change some parameters in function of line to find a correct line which separated groups and make an iteration of the iteration parameter. By default it is trying to find a correct line 15000 times. If we use following code, svmtrain will try 100000 times to find a corrected line. But the time of training is naturally longer.

```
options.MaxIter = 100000;
my_svm_struct = svmtrain((Training, Group, 'Options', options);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the optional `'options'` parameter of the `svmtrain` function (`MaxIter`). The [documentation of svmtrain](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/svmtrain.html) contains more information about this.

You will need to make the options struct with either `statset` if you're using SMO (default) or `optimset` if you're using the QP solver.