# Can I use neural network in this case?

Tags: neural-network

can I use neural networks or svm or etc, if my output data is 27680 that all of them are zero and just one of them is one?
I mean that Is it right to do this?

when I use SVM I have this error:
Error using seqminopt>seqminoptImpl (line 198)
No convergence achieved within maximum number of iterations.

Comment: You mean that your input vector is 27680, which has 27679 zeros and only one value equals to 1?

Comment: hi . yes I mean that if I want to train this network and my input (features or observed variables) of network is X and is 27680*2 and my output of network is Y (target) and is 27680*1 ....when I want to use data for Y, it has 27679 zeros and only one value equals to 1...Can I use neural network or SVM and etc? Is it right

Comment: Sounds to me like you could improve your feature vectors. 27680 classes with binary flags is not really ideal for gradient descent. If you're performing text classification, go with e.g. Naive Bayes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVMs are usually binary classifiers. Basically that means that they seperate your datapoints into two groups, which signals whether a datapoint does or doesn't belong to a class. Common strategies for solving multi-class problems with SVMs are one-vs-rest and one-vs-one. In the case of one-vs-rest, you would train one classifier per class, which would be 27,680 for you. In the case of one-vs-one, you would train (K over 2) = (K(K-1))/2 classifiers, so in your case around 38 million. As you can see, both numbers are rather high, so I would be pessimistic about your probability of successfully solving your problem with SVMs.
Nevertheless you can try to increase the maximum amount iterations as described in [another stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683381/increasing-the-number-of-iterations-with-multisvm). Maybe it still works.

You can use Neural Nets for your task and a 1-of-K output is nothing unusual. However, even with only one hidden layer of 500 neurons (and using the input and output vector sizes mentioned in your comment) you will have (27680*2*500) + (500*27680) = 41,520,000 weights in your network. So I would expect rather long training times (although a Google employee would probably laugh about these numbers). You will also most likely need a lot of training examples, unless your input is really simple.

As an alternative you might look into Decision Trees/Random Forests, Naive Bayes or kNN.

Comment: X is train input and Y is train output...when we want to get the value of Y we need just 2 value of X for test data.. I upload an image in this link   http://www.axgig.com/viewer.php?file=94461789190863693715.jpg     that show the things that said you can see that ,and see just one data is green...X has 2 dimension and y has 1 dimension...thank you

Comment: So you mean that you have about 27000 examples (and not 27000 dimensions) that you are projecting onto a single dimension with values 1/0 for yes/no? Then a SVM should be able to find a good solution for that. If it runs out of iterations then try using a non-linear decision boundary (e.g. RBF) and increase the amount data points that may be misclassified (usually by increasing a C-value).

Comment: yes, I have two class A and B to seperate (A is shown with zero and B shown whit one) that when we see dataset in all cases classA has 27679 zeros and classB has 1 one(only the place of 1 is changing in these cases,all the time we have 27679 zeros and 1 one)...in all the time for all data examples we have this 27679 zeros and just 1 one...I want to know for project like this can SVM or neural networks get right solution? like this image  axgig.com/viewer.php?file=94461789190863693715.jpg  all data is in claasA and just one of them is in classB

Comment: So apparently you have a bunch of training examples and every example is a group of ~27000 datapoints of which only a single point belongs to class A. If all points of class A are kinda similar then you might just use a SVM across all of those examples (many points in A + many points in B as a training set). You may have to throw out lots of points in B, otherwise your training set will be heavily skewed towards B. If A depends on all other points per example then you might try using Regression to predict the coordinates of A and pick the point closest to it as A.

Comment: thanks a lot
 I  can omit some of point in classA. but I think number of point in A is large yet, so I will use regression..I really appreciate you for your help.